# If a homogeneous linear equation has a periodic solution, then the non-homogeneous equation also has

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, periodic-functions

Let $A(t)$ continuous in the interval $I=[0,\tau]$. Suppose that

$$x'=A(t)x$$

The solution $\psi \equiv 0$ , is the only solution whit period $\tau$. So for every continuous function $b(t)$, there is a single solution $\varphi_b$, of period $\tau$ of $x'=A(t)x+b(t)$.

And exist a constant $C>0$, independent of $b$, such that $|\varphi_b|\le C|b|$.

Another way of writing this problem is:

> If the equation $x' = A(t)x$ has no $\tau$-periodic solutions other than the
> zero function, then the equation $x' = A(t)x + b(t)$ has a unique $\tau$-periodic
> solution.

This result seems to be easy to prove, but I am having trouble proving it. I was able to prove, only used that $b(t)$ is also periodic of period $\tau$.

Comment: check this book: http://library.lol/main/21EE7883F29F94EA362109C87C5FB18F